# Concept Map using D3.JS : straight lines instead of curves

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, concept

http://bl.ocks.org/virtuald/ea7438cb8c6913196d8e

The above is a link to a smaple concept map. The idea of highliting the curves upon mouse hovering is great and dynamic.

are there any others samples , where INSTEAD  of such curves, ONLY STRAIGHT LINES (horizontal and vertical) are highlighted upon clicking on the data of interest to show its assoiated attributes?

can this map with the curvy lines be modified so that a striaght lines only appear instead???  ACTUALLY the cuves are not always appropriate espicially if you are going to display  a data extracted from an excel table or sheet with a lot of columns linked to each other.   How can this be implemented please?... Thank you v, much for any information or clue.

Answer (score 0):

To make straight lines instead of curves, remove the use the d3.svg.diagonal in creating the "links":

```
// links
var link = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'links').selectAll(".link")
    .data(data.links)
  .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id })
    .attr("d", function(d){
      var y1 = d.outer.y * Math.cos(projectX(d.outer.x)),
          x1 = -d.outer.y * Math.sin(projectX(d.outer.x)),
          y2 = d.inner.y + rect_height/2,
          x2 = d.outer.x > 180 ? d.inner.x : d.inner.x + rect_width;
        return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "L" + x2 + "," + y2;
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(d) { return get_color(d.inner.name); })
    .attr('stroke-width', link_width);
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="name" content="Concept Map" />
 <meta name="description" content="An abstract mapping for parameters. Works best if first tag is 'unique' among the tracklist, and the second tag applies to multiple tracks"/>
 <meta name="mintags" content="2" />
 <meta name="maxtags" content="2" />
 <title>Jam Cellar 2014-05-06</title>

<style>

svg {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}

text {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.inner_node rect {
    pointer-events: all;
}

.inner_node rect.highlight {
    stroke: #315B7E;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.outer_node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.outer_node circle.highlight
{
    stroke: #315B7E;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link {
    fill: none;
}

</style> 
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
//
// Generated by the Exaile Playlist Analyzer plugin.
// (C) 2014 Dustin Spicuzza <dustin@virtualroadside.com>
//
// This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0
// International License. To view a copy of this license, visit
// http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/.
//
// Inspired by http://www.findtheconversation.com/concept-map/
// Loosely based on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550
//


var data = [[120, ["like", "call response", "dramatic intro", "has breaks", "male vocalist", "silly", "swing"]], [150, ["brassy", "like", "calm energy", "female vocalist", "swing", "fun"]], [170, ["calm energy", "instrumental", "swing", "like", "happy"]], [140, ["has breaks", "male vocalist", "swing", "piano", "banjo", "chill"]], [160, ["calm energy", "instrumental", "swing", "like", "interesting"]], [140, ["brassy", "like", "energy", "dramatic intro", "male vocalist", "baseball", "swing"]], [170, ["instrumental", "interesting", "high energy", "like", "swing"]], [140, ["instrumental", "energy", "like", "swing"]], [200, ["instrumental", "brassy", "dramatic intro", "like", "swing"]], [160, ["male vocalist", "brassy", "swing", "like", "my favorites"]], [130, ["like", "interesting", "dramatic intro", "male vocalist", "silly", "swing", "gospel"]], [160, ["like", "long intro", "announcer", "energy", "swing", "female vocalist"]], [170, ["instrumental", "swing", "bass", "like"]], [150, ["like", "interesting", "has breaks", "instrumental", "chunky", "swing", "banjo", "trumpet"]], [170, ["like", "has breaks", "male vocalist", "silly", "swing", "banjo"]], [190, ["instrumental", "banjo", "swing"]], [130, ["instrumental", "brassy", "banjo", "like", "swing"]], [160, ["brassy", "like", "energy", "instrumental", "big band", "jam", "swing"]], [150, ["like", "male vocalist", "live", "swing", "piano", "banjo", "chill"]], [150, ["like", "trick ending", "instrumental", "chunky", "swing", "chill"]], [120, ["brassy", "like", "female vocalist", "swing", "chill", "energy buildup"]], [150, ["brassy", "like", "interesting", "instrumental", "swing", "piano"]], [190, ["brassy", "like", "long intro", "energy", "baseball", "swing", "female vocalist"]], [180, ["calm energy", "female vocalist", "live", "like", "swing"]], [200, ["banjo", "like", "long intro", "interesting", "energy", "my favorites", "male vocalist", "silly", "swing", "fun", "balboa"]], [150, ["brassy", "calm energy", "chunky", "instrumental", "old-timey", "live", "swing"]], [160, ["like", "call response", "interesting", "instrumental", "calm energy", "swing"]], [180, ["interesting", "swing", "fast", "male vocalist"]], [150, ["calm energy", "chunky", "swing", "female vocalist", "like"]], [180, ["like", "has breaks", "male vocalist", "chunky", "silly", "swing"]], [140, ["instrumental", "brassy", "dramatic intro", "swing", "chill"]], [150, ["male vocalist", "trumpet", "like", "swing"]], [150, ["instrumental", "energy", "like", "has breaks", "swing"]], [180, ["brassy", "like", "energy", "has breaks", "instrumental", "has calm", "swing"]], [150, ["female vocalist", "swing"]], [170, ["instrumental", "brassy", "energy", "swing"]], [170, ["calm energy", "instrumental", "energy", "like", "swing"]], [190, ["brassy", "like", "instrumental", "high energy", "swing", "trumpet"]], [160, ["male vocalist", "energy", "swing", "old-timey"]], [170, ["like", "oldies", "my favorites", "fast", "male vocalist", "high energy", "swing"]]];

// transform the data into a useful representation
// 1 is inner, 2, is outer

// need: inner, outer, links
//
// inner: 
// links: { inner: outer: }


var outer = d3.map();
var inner = [];
var links = [];

var outerId = [0];

data.forEach(function(d){
 
 if (d == null)
  return;
 
 i = { id: 'i' + inner.length, name: d[0], related_links: [] };
 i.related_nodes = [i.id];
 inner.push(i);
 
 if (!Array.isArray(d[1]))
  d[1] = [d[1]];
 
 d[1].forEach(function(d1){
  
  o = outer.get(d1);
  
  if (o == null)
  {
   o = { name: d1, id: 'o' + outerId[0], related_links: [] };
   o.related_nodes = [o.id];
   outerId[0] = outerId[0] + 1; 
   
   outer.set(d1, o);
  }
  
  // create the links
  l = { id: 'l-' + i.id + '-' + o.id, inner: i, outer: o }
  links.push(l);
  
  // and the relationships
  i.related_nodes.push(o.id);
  i.related_links.push(l.id);
  o.related_nodes.push(i.id);
  o.related_links.push(l.id);
 });
});

data = {
 inner: inner,
 outer: outer.values(),
 links: links
}

// sort the data -- TODO: have multiple sort options
outer = data.outer;
data.outer = Array(outer.length);


var i1 = 0;
var i2 = outer.length - 1;

for (var i = 0; i < data.outer.length; ++i)
{
 if (i % 2 == 1)
  data.outer[i2--] = outer[i];
 else
  data.outer[i1++] = outer[i];
}

console.log(data.outer.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b.related_links.length; }, 0) / data.outer.length);


// from d3 colorbrewer: 
// This product includes color specifications and designs developed by Cynthia Brewer (http://colorbrewer.org/).
var colors = ["#a50026","#d73027","#f46d43","#fdae61","#fee090","#ffffbf","#e0f3f8","#abd9e9","#74add1","#4575b4","#313695"]
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([60, 220])
    .range([colors.length-1, 0])
    .clamp(true);

var diameter = 960;
var rect_width = 40;
var rect_height = 14;

var link_width = "1px"; 

var il = data.inner.length;
var ol = data.outer.length;

var inner_y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, il])
    .range([-(il * rect_height)/2, (il * rect_height)/2]);

mid = (data.outer.length/2.0)
var outer_x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, mid, mid, data.outer.length])
    .range([15, 170, 190 ,355]);

var outer_y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.outer.length])
    .range([0, diameter / 2 - 120]);


// setup positioning
data.outer = data.outer.map(function(d, i) { 
    d.x = outer_x(i);
    d.y = diameter/3;
    return d;
});

data.inner = data.inner.map(function(d, i) { 
    d.x = -(rect_width / 2);
    d.y = inner_y(i);
    return d;
});


function get_color(name)
{
    var c = Math.round(color(name));
    if (isNaN(c))
        return '#dddddd'; // fallback color
    
    return colors[c];
}

// Can't just use d3.svg.diagonal because one edge is in normal space, the
// other edge is in radial space. Since we can't just ask d3 to do projection
// of a single point, do it ourselves the same way d3 would do it.  


function projectX(x)
{
    return ((x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI) - (Math.PI/2);
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");
    

// links
var link = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'links').selectAll(".link")
    .data(data.links)
  .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id })
    .attr("d", function(d){
      var y1 = d.outer.y * Math.cos(projectX(d.outer.x)),
          x1 = -d.outer.y * Math.sin(projectX(d.outer.x)),
          y2 = d.inner.y + rect_height/2,
          x2 = d.outer.x > 180 ? d.inner.x : d.inner.x + rect_width;
        return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "L" + x2 + "," + y2;
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(d) { return get_color(d.inner.name); })
    .attr('stroke-width', link_width);

// outer nodes

var onode = svg.append('g').selectAll(".outer_node")
    .data(data.outer)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "outer_node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
  
onode.append("circle")
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id })
    .attr("r", 4.5);
  
onode.append("circle")
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('visibility', 'hidden');
  
onode.append("text")
 .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id + '-txt'; })
    .attr("dy", ".31em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  
// inner nodes
  
var inode = svg.append('g').selectAll(".inner_node")
    .data(data.inner)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "inner_node")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"})
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
  
inode.append('rect')
    .attr('width', rect_width)
    .attr('height', rect_height)
    .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id; })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return get_color(d.name); });
  
inode.append("text")
 .attr('id', function(d) { return d.id + '-txt'; })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rect_width/2 + ", " + rect_height * .75 + ")")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// need to specify x/y/etc

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter - 150 + "px");

function mouseover(d)
{
 // bring to front
 d3.selectAll('.links .link').sort(function(a, b){ return d.related_links.indexOf(a.id); }); 
 
    for (var i = 0; i < d.related_nodes.length; i++)
    {
        d3.select('#' + d.related_nodes[i]).classed('highlight', true);
        d3.select('#' + d.related_nodes[i] + '-txt').attr("font-weight", 'bold');
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < d.related_links.length; i++)
        d3.select('#' + d.related_links[i]).attr('stroke-width', '5px');
}

function mouseout(d)
{    
    for (var i = 0; i < d.related_nodes.length; i++)
    {
        d3.select('#' + d.related_nodes[i]).classed('highlight', false);
        d3.select('#' + d.related_nodes[i] + '-txt').attr("font-weight", 'normal');
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < d.related_links.length; i++)
        d3.select('#' + d.related_links[i]).attr('stroke-width', link_width);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in the code that I'm working with.

```
    $('path.link').each(function (ind, path) {
        let curveTo = $(path).attr('d'),
            lineTo = curveTo.replace(/C/, 'L');
        $(path).attr('d', lineTo);
    })
```

You have to give `.link` class to all the `path` elements beforehand.

```
          theDiagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
          ehv.selectAll('.links')
            .data(allLinks)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .append('path')
            .attr({
                'class': 'link', //Like this.
                'd': theDiagonal
            });
```

CSS

```
path.link, path.drawing-path {
    stroke-dasharray: 3, 1;
    fill: none;
    stroke: gray;
}
```